# file upload is not working in gravity repeater plugin wordpress

Tags: wordpress, forms, repeater, gravity-forms-plugin, gravity

**file upload is not working in gravity repeater plugin wordpress.** 
Once you click on next button after select file, it hide whole form.
it applies display none on whole form

I have used "Gravity Forms Repeater Add-On". when i add upload filed in repeater and make it as require and then it stopped working. but if i remove that require field in gravity form then this works.

please check https://www.gospelmusicshared.com/singles-form

**There are 4 steps.**
**step 1 :** Add any detail.
**step 2 :** - Select album option in radio.
- Add any data don't leave any option empty.
**Step 3 :** in this step you can see upload song this is repeater field.
-This filed is required field. Now select .m4a or .wav or .flac and click to next after that form is not visible.

Comment: It doesn't answer your question but if you're looking for an alternate to this style of repeater functionality, check out my plugin [Gravity Forms Nested Forms](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-nested-forms/).

Comment: Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

Creator of the Gravity Forms Repeater Add-on here. Unfortunately I have deprecated that plugin due to lack of time and interest. Luckily the guys over at GravityWiz have developed an alternative. Go checkout [Gravity Forms Nested Forms](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-nested-forms/?ref=145)!